# For loop on column in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to calculate an equation per row in a dataframe and assign the value to a new column :

```
def exercise_02():
    df_region = df.groupby(by = "region").sum()
    for i in range(len(df_region)):
        i == 0
        df_region["w_avg"] = df1["2018_x"][i] * df1["2018_y"][i] / df1["2018_y"][i]
        i = i+1
    result = df_region
    return result
```

when I only write this, it shows this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8QHx.png)

As you can see, the column **w_avg** has been created but it contains the same value.

I tried to solve by adding [i] after the column name inside the loop:

```
def exercise_02():
    df_region = df.groupby(by = "region").sum()
    for i in range(len(df_region)):
        i == 0
        **df_region["w_avg"][i]** = df1["2018_x"][i] * df1["2018_y"][i] / df1["2018_y"][i]
        i = i+1
    result = df_region
    return result
```

But instead, I get this error message:

```
 if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'w_avg'
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing about DataFrames is that you do *not* need to loop. They are vectorised. If you were to change your (homework?) function to

```py
def exercise_02():
    df_region = df.groupby(by = "region").sum()
    df_region["w_avg"] = df_region["2018_x"] * df_region["2018_y"] / df_region["2018_y"]
    return df_region
```

However, I notice that you are mixing up multiple dataframes. If they do not have the same size, you *will* run into issues regarding length/index issues. That really depends on you relation between `df_region`, `df`, and `df_1`.

The reason I mention the latter is that you more or less accidentally(?) used variables outside the scope of your function. Your function has no parameters, but uses `df` and `df1` inside its scope. So, there's definitely something that is missing in your question you need to understand yourself, or convey to the community to completely 'anwer' your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation! IT worked (of course).
I made a mistake actually, I was supposed to only use df_region in this exercise, so not mix the 3 dataframes